# diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[Any] with recursion

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement BST in Scala. I want to add a node to binary tree by '+' operator. However I get two errors during compilation time

```
Error:(39, 46) diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[Any]
    starting with method orderingToOrdered in object Ordered
    def +[A: Ordering](v: A) : Tree[Any] = add(this, v)

Error:(39, 46) not enough arguments for method add: (implicit evidence$1: Ordering[Any])A$A47.this.Tree[Any].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
  def +[A: Ordering](v: A) : Tree[Any] = add(this, v)
```

Here is the code.

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]{
  def add[A: Ordering](tree: Tree[A], v: A) : Tree[A] = tree match {
    case EmptyTree => Node(EmptyTree, v, EmptyTree)
    case Node(l, x, r) => {
      if(x.compare(v) == 1)
        Node(add(l, v), x, r)
      else
        Node(l, x, add (r, v))
    }
  }

  def +[A: Ordering](v: A) : Tree[Any] = add(this, v)
}
```

Can someone help me and tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the interface of the operator `+`.

```
def add[A: Ordering](tree: Tree[A], v: A) : Tree[A]
```

The `add` function accepts a `Tree[A]` and returns a `Tree[A]` where `A` is constrained by the typeclass `Ordering`. Nothing wrong here (but it would better to define it in the companion object of `Tree`).

```
def +[A: Ordering](v: A) : Tree[Any] = add(this, v)
```

The `+` function accepts a value (you're assuming that the `tree` parameter of `add` is `this` here) of type `A` which is also constrained by the typeclass `Ordering`.

The first issue here is, that you return a `Tree[Any]`. I'm assuming you meant `Tree[A]`.

The second issue is, that the `A` in the function `+` is **not** the type parameter `A` which `this` is referring to. So you probably meant:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+A: Ordering] {
  ...
  def +(v: A) : Tree[A] = add(this, v)
}
```

If this is not what you want, you have to constrain `A` in the function `+` by the typeclass `Ordering`:

```
sealed trait Tree[A] {
  ...
  def +(v: A)(implicit ev: Ordering[A]): Tree[A] = add(this, v)
}
```

In this case `A` may not be covariant anymore, because it occurs in an invariant position.

**Edit**: As mentioned below, there is also the opportunity of introducing a new type `B` in the function `+`. The overall code could look like this:

```
object Tree {
  def add[A](tree: Tree[A], v: A)(implicit ev: Ordering[A]): Tree[A] = ...
}
sealed trait Tree[+A] {
  def +[B >: A](v: B)(implicit ev: Ordering[B]): Tree[B] = Tree.add(this, v)
}
... implementation of trait Tree
```

**2nd Edit**: In the example above it is necessary to introduce a super type and not a sub type `B`, because the function `Tree.add` would need the typeclass `Ordering[A]` - which we can not provide.

The following makes no sense, because it only proves that values of type `B` can be ordered.

```
def +[B <: A](v: B)(implicit ev: Ordering[B]): Tree[B] = ???
```

And this does not even compile, because `A` occurs in an invariant position.

```
def +[B <: A](v: B)(implicit ev: Ordering[A]): Tree[B] = ???
```

So to achieve that `A` does not occur in an invariant position and to prove that values of type `B` as well as values of type `A` can be ordered, we have to introduce `B` as a super type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that converting in sealed trait **Tree[+A]** to **Tree[A]**  breaks any use of case classes i.e. **case class Node[A](left: Tree[A], value: A, right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]** or
**case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]**

Comment: Another possibility would be the introduction of a new type `B` which is a super type of `A` or `A` itself: 

`def +[B >: A](v: B)(implicit ev: Ordering[B]): Tree[B] = add(this, v)` 

... but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: That is an excellent solution. Can you tell me why we are introducing a super type instead of a sub type? Or provide some materials about covariance/invariance/contravariance?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope this helps. You can read about variance in the language specification http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html